# Query string starting with zero (0) returns non desired values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have a QUERY and, above it, I have some cells that, when filled, add conditions to the QUERY.
As my formula is today:

```
" and lower(Col4) contains '"& D11 & "'"
```

In that case from the image, when I fill the "Nº PP" filter on D11 (which is usually a string of numbers), when I type something that starts with a zero (like "040222", the case from the image) it returns everything that contains "40222".

I get zero results if I change the formula to:

```
" and lower(Col4) = '"& D11 & "'"
```

Every other case when it doesn't start with a zero, it queries correctly.
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet? try to add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

it should work if you use regex:

```
"and lower(Col4) matches '"&TO_TEXT(D11)&"'"
```

Comment: Tried it, but returns no results :/

Comment: @GabrielSabiá can you share a copy of your sheet?